# Using OpenCV from F#

Tags: f#, opencv

I would like to analyse the colour of a picture. Is it possible to use the OpenCV library with F# (the only language I am familiar with). If yes, do you know where I can find a tutorial/book on this subject (OpenCV 2 Computer Vision seems great but is written for C++ users).

Comment: "the only language I am familiar with" -- lucky you that your mind has not been polluted with older paradigms.

Comment: ;). I am reconciled with code thanks to this language

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is definitely possible using F# with one of .NET wrappers over OpenCV. For example, below is the "Hello World" snippet that comes with [EmguCV](http://www.emgu.com) translated from C# to F# that works perfectly:

```
open Emgu.CV
open Emgu.CV.CvEnum
open Emgu.CV.Structure

[<EntryPoint>]
let main(_) =
    let win1 = "Test Window"
    CvInvoke.cvNamedWindow(win1) |> ignore
    use img = new Image<Bgr, byte>(400, 200, Bgr(255.,0.,0.))
    let f = ref (MCvFont(FONT.CV_FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 1., 1.))
    img.Draw("Hello, World", f, System.Drawing.Point(10,80), Bgr(0.,255.,0.))
    CvInvoke.cvShowImage(win1, img.Ptr)
    CvInvoke.cvWaitKey(0) |> ignore
    CvInvoke.cvDestroyWindow(win1)
    0
```

EmguCV web site and installation provide some [C# tutorials](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Tutorial) that may give you initial traction. Your mileage may vary, depending on your F# interop skills among other factors.

Answer (score 2):

[Emgu CV](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) is the most popular option with [Emgu CV Essentials](https://www.packtpub.com/application-development/emgu-cv-essentials) book. Two other .NET OpenCV wrapper projects:

- [OpenCvSharp](https://github.com/shimat/opencvsharp)
- [OpenCV.NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/OpenCV.Net)

Answer (score 1):

[EmguCV](http://www.emgu.com/) is a .NET wrapper for OpenCV. It should work with F# as well.